# Is there a name for a measurable function $f:(X,\mathcal{S})\to (Y,\mathcal{B}_Y)$?

Tags: measure-theory, definition

Many relevant results for a measurable function $f:(X,\Sigma_X)\to(Y,\Sigma_Y)$ are obtained by assuming that $\Sigma_Y$ is a Borel $\sigma$-algebra with respect to some topology on $Y$. For example:

1. $f$ is measurable if and only if for every open (or closed) set $U\in\mathcal{B}_Y$ we have that $f^{-1}(U)\in\Sigma_X$.
2. If $(Y,\Sigma_Y)=(\mathbb{C},\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{C}})$: $f$ is measurable if and only if so are $\text{Re}(f)$ and $\text{Im}(f)$.
3. If $(Y,\Sigma_Y)=(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}})$: $f$ is measurable if and only if $\{f\le c\}:=\{ r\in\mathbb{R} : f(r) \le c\}\in\mathcal{S}$ for every $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

We lose some generality if we assume in $(1)$ that $f$ is Borel, or if we assume in $(2)$ and $(3)$ that $f$ is either Borel or Lebesgue.

I was thus wondering if measurable functions $(X,\Sigma_X)\to(Y,\mathcal{B}_Y)$ have a name.

Comment: Borel function?

Comment: @BCLC I've always seen Borel functions being defined as $(X,\mathcal{B}_X)\to(Y,\mathcal{B}_Y)$. However, the $\sigma$-algebra in the domain being Borel is unnecesary to show any of the results above.

Comment: You can say $f$ is $\Sigma_X$ - $\mathcal{B}(Y)$ measurable. Some people say $f$ is Borel measurable, but I like the more precise way of writing it.